# How to obtain Domain name via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, domain-name

Is there a way to obtain the domain name of the current page by using javascript in a browser (IE, FireFox, etc) ?

Comment: which windows machine? The client or the server?

Answer (score 141):

If you are asking about the machine name of the host that served up the current page, you can find that with

```
window.location.hostname
```

If you are asking about the name of the machine that is displaying the page in a browser, that information is restricted by browsers for security purposes.

Comment: +1 for reading the question properly, unlike everyone else.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `document.domain` to get domain name.

Comment: Simple, elegant, what I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

`window.location.host`

**EDIT:** If you meant the domain of the client machine, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: except on ie, which have something i would rather not to say..... active....x.